# Python multithread queue peeking

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I have a multithreaded program that has a management thread that at regular intervals puts jobs of various types in a queue shared among many worker threads, that pick jobs up as they are put in the queue (it's a `queue.SimpleQueue`).
The time that a worker thread needs to finish a job can vary greatly, so basically my need is, from the management thread, to know whether a given job type is already in the queue to avoid putting in another one of the same type. However I see no way to peek into the queue.

Comment: This should have a coding example. It's too general.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a separate data structure to keep track of the tasks put in the queue. A good idea is to generate unique task ID for each task and put them on a dictionary.

When a task completes, you set an attribute (say, `done=True`) using that task ID.

Using a external data store (a database or Redis for example) might be easier to manage this in a distributed system.

Comment: How does that help me see when a job has been processed by a worker?